# div height not set based on inner divs

Tags: html, css

I have a div as a container which contains two columns
both columns have dynamic sizes, and I need the top container to take on the inner divs sizes, so that my content below the container lines up correctly

```
#container{
    width:800px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#leftdetails{
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height: 100%;
}
#rightdetails{
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

When I inspect the container the height is 0

```
     <div id="reamcontent">
            <div id="rightdetails">
                lots of content
            </div>
            <div id="leftdetails">
                lots of content
            </div>
     </div>
<div id"other">
 this overlaps the reamcontent
</div>
```

Comment: You can set `overflow: auto;` on `#reamcontent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a clear div this will fix the height

The outer div is collapsing because the two child divs inside of it are floating

css

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

html

```
<div id="reamcontent">
    <div id="rightdetails">lots of content</div>
    <div id="leftdetails">lots of content</div>
    <div class="clear"></div> <!-- div added -->
</div>
```

Comment: perfect!
Curious, why is it a class?

Comment: so that you can use it multiple times in a page

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/):

```
#reamcontent:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```